# How to view existing projects in newer version of the Eclipse on another computer?

Tags: eclipse

On one of my machines, I am using PDT Eclipse Europa and have a workspace at D:/folder/myworkspace.

Then I log into my another machine, where I have just installed Eclipse Galileo. And it asks me to select workspace, and I choose M:/folder/myworkspace (a network drive, could have named it same as D:/ ) and it opens up the workspace. The problem is it doesnt show up the projects already existing in that workspace.

What I'll have to do to get that list of projects in the newer version of eclipse?

Will I have to import projects? I dont want to create copies. May be there is any setting to play with?? Please help.

Thanks.

Please see: I can view all of the files on new machine using windows explorer. So there isn't any problem of accessibility on the network.

**UPDATE**

OK, I have got it working. Actually what happened was that last time when I used eclipse, it was not closed/shut down properly as the system had crashed. Now I reopened the eclipse and closed all of the files and the closed it. Then I started eclipse on new machine and, guess what, magic, I could see list of my projects !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I have got it working.

Actually what happened was that last time when I used eclipse, it was not closed/shut down properly as the system had crashed.

Now I reopened the eclipse and closed all of the files and the closed it.

Then I started eclipse on my newer machine and, guess what, magic, I could see the list of my projects!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Galileo is dealing with it but having a workspace on a network drive has always been trouble. Try fo import the projects one by one (right click -> import -> existing projects into workspace) and select that workspace. Was it working with Europa on the network drive?

Comment: yes .. it is still on a network drive. Its a desktop and newer machine is a laptop. So I want to set it up for my both of the machines.

Comment: Ok cool. Just wasn't sure, the networking part was always a little tricky in earlier eclipse releases

Answer (score 0):

Not a sure answer but I would create a new Workspace locally and import into that workspace all the projects from the network drive. There may be issues with the paths in the networked workspace.

---

Update: I just looked at the workspace preference files and it appears that a projects location is an absolute pate so the only way a workspace on a network drive would work is if the path on all machines is the same.

Comment: so how would you update the files on the server? for example, to access the changed files on another machine on same network??

Comment: Your project files would still be on the network drive so they would be updated fine the only thing that would not be the same between computers would be the workspace preferences.